# how to see my print/NSLog outputs when using Instruments Automation, with simulator?

Tags: ios, instruments, ios-ui-automation, nslog, xcode-instruments

I'm new to Instruments, and I'm trying to use Instruments Automation to send location events to my Xcode Swift project, which uses MapKit, but using a SIMULATOR (c.f. real device).

I've got this working by:

- running my project in PROFILE mode in Xcode
- then going to instruments automation with a script that uses "setLocationWithOptions"

But neither in Xcode or Instruments do I see my normal log output (print or NSLog) I use to monitor the app?  How would I see print line outputs when doing this?  Or is the different approach I should be taking?

Comment: Maybe this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569134/how-to-see-nslog-from-console-app-when-using-instruments

Comment: @Greg Just a clarification, when you choose Console from the Instruments jump bar, there's nothing in the console?

Comment: @naomimichiko - no actually - they had the same issue there when trying to see the output when using a simulator (c.f. real device)

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk - nothing in the console here...  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Xcode 8

If talk about simulator, you need to run your application first and then, record **running** application through you instrument, Zombies, for example.

What you need to choose for recording:
[select running application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI5Kr.jpg)